# CloudFormation script stuck in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED, AWSLambdaInternal needs GetObject permissions. How to resolve?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation stack stuck in a state of UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED.

The error message I'm seeing, associated with the creation of a Lambda, is:

```
Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials 
have permission to GetObject for <codepipeline-bucket-name>/<file-name>]. S3 
Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied (Service: 
AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; 
Request ID: <request-id>)
```

I have double checked that the IAM Role associated with the stack has the correct S3 permissions, but I don't think it's CloudFormation that's throwing the permission error. I think it's AWSLambdaInternal service.

I have a dozen other stacks that use the same IAM role and I've not had this problem. I even tried making the specific S3 object public to see if that might be the problem. But I can only assume that AWSLambdaInternal does not have S3 GetObject permission.  I even tried adding sts:AssumeRole permissions for lambda.awsamazon.com to the IAM role the CloudFormation script uses, but that didn't change anything.

The stack was working fine until I decided to move the Lambda function it creates into a VPC.

Comment: How are you creating the stack? Can you share the Cloudformation template?

Comment: Here's the section of the CloudFormation script that deals with the Lambda:

`Lambda:
    Properties:
      CodeUri: s3://<bucket-name>/<file-name>
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SECRETSMANAGER:
            Ref: SecretsManagerName
      Handler: index.handler
      MemorySize: 128
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - LambdaRole
        - Arn
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Timeout: 30
      Tracing: PassThrough
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function`

Answer (score 1):

Actually the status `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED` means that you not only have update failed, but also failed rollback, which actually should never be happen.

You should check if you have changed any of `CloudFormation` managed resources manually and if you sure that you didn't - report your problem to `CloudFormation` support.

Comment: While AWS Basic support is free, they will not assist with technical issues.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda function that you moved into a VPC -- does it not by any chance serve a custom CloudFormation resource for you? Because when rollback fails for me it's usually my own doing - when I have messed up with the custom resource's lambda function and it fails. When in doubt I usually make the delete action for the custom resource a no-op, or make it always report success even if it fails (and then I have to manually delete the resource).

If the lambda function is indeed responsible for the management of a custom resource then you should 1) move it back where it was; 2) create a new lambda function which you know will be accessible and will work; 3) only then switch to using the lambda function.

In CloudFormation's stack events listing, look what resource update failed. The individual error is not as important as the resource it was triggered for.

Comment: It's not a custom CloudFormation resource.  The CloudFormation resource associated with this error message is just a normal Lambda function.  It's not even Lambda@Edge.